# cp: 0ALX48~X.M4V: No such file or directory

Tags: filenames, cp

I am copying files *en masse* to a new NAS and this error came up in the logs:

```bsh
cp: readynas/libraries/Television/Clerks/Season 1/0ALX48~X.M4V: No such file or directory
```

Attempting to copy the file directly shows something funny about the filename, is that actually a tab?

```bsh
Clerks/Season 1$ cp 01x05\ -\ \    Dante\ and\ Randal\ and\ Jay\ and\ Silent\ Bob\ and\ a\ Bunch\ of\ New\ Characters\ and\ Lando\,\ Take\ Part\ in\ a\ Whole\ Bunch\ of\ Movie\ Parodies.m4v ~/Desktop/
cp: cannot stat '01x05 - '$'\t''Dante and Randal and Jay and Silent Bob and a Bunch of New Characters and Lando, Take Part in a Whole Bunch of Movie Parodies.m4v': No such file or directory
```

List also throws an error

```bsh
Clerks/Season 1$ ls -al
ls: '01x05 - '$'\t''Dante and Randal and Jay and Silent Bob and a Bunch of New Characters and Lando, Take Part in a Whole Bunch of Movie Parodies.m4v': No such file or directory
total 939264
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 matthew users         0 Jan 19 07:05  .
drwxrwxr-x+ 3 matthew users         0 May  6  2018  ..
-rwxrwxr-x  1 matthew users 185548662 May  5  2018 '01x05 - '$'\t''Dante and Randal and Jay and Silent Bob and a Bunch of New Characters and Lando, Take Part in a Whole Bunch of Movie Parodies.m4v'
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 matthew users 156186223 May  5  2018  s01e01.mp4
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 matthew users 158159531 May  5  2018  s01e02.mp4
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 matthew users 155609221 May  5  2018  s01e03.mp4
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 matthew users 163277414 May  5  2018  s01e04.mp4
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 matthew users 142775050 May  5  2018  s01e06.mp4
```

Attempting to change the file's name with `mv` fails slightly differently:

```bsh
Clerks/Season 1$ mv 01x05\ -\ \    Dante\ and\ Randal\ and\ Jay\ and\ Silent\ Bob\ and\ a\ Bunch\ of\ New\ Characters\ and\ Lando\,\ Take\ Part\ in\ a\ Whole\ Bunch\ of\ Movie\ Parodies.m4v 15.m4v
mv: cannot stat '01x05 - '$'\t''Dante and Randal and Jay and Silent Bob and a Bunch of New Characters and Lando, Take Part in a Whole Bunch of Movie Parodies.m4v': No such file or directory
```

The file may be doomed, hoping someone has an idea how it can be saved.

Answer (score 1):

Follow-up: seems the mount over smbv1 was the issue, was able to ssh into original NAS and ran the mv command successfully.

As an aside, the ReadyNAS family and Netgear generally are entirely dead to me.

Comment: Yes. smb is a microsoft protocol. And microsoft file-systems are limited in what file-names are valid. There is a ton of code in there, than has no other purpose than to stop it working when you use "invalid" characters.

Comment: If you word this an an answer, then next time I am here, I will up-vote it.

Comment: if you word this as an answer, then next time I am here, I will accept it :)